# Every derived table must have its own alias (sql & php)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM `list_lazada` WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%' 
        UNION All
        SELECT *
        FROM `list_simulation` WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%' 
    )
```

running sql 
"Every derived table must have its own alias"

please help?

Comment: just add an alias after the subquery parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

Provide an alias name for sub-query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM `list_lazada` WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%' 
        UNION All
        SELECT *
        FROM `list_simulation` WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%' 
    ) t1
```

Hope this should solve your problem.

Comment: It Works, Thanks you so much :)